# CakePHP Can't access to other models on testing

Tags: cakephp, testing

Here is my test controller :

```
 public function testAdd() {
   $data = array(
       'Article' => array(
           'id' => '1',
           'text' => 'blablabla',
       ),

   );

   $result = $this->testAction(
       '/articles/add',
       array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')
   );
   debug($result);
 }
```

So I can access to the current model in the controller ($this->Article) but i can't load other models via loadModel.
Clarification : The code written in the controller works perfectly when i load other models, the problem appears ONLY when i want to test my controller.

Best regards.

Comment: aren't you using `public $fixtures = array(...)` here? Also you forgot to mention the cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Why do you need to access another model in order to test a controller action? Models should be tested in the models tests.

Comment: I'm using cakePHP 2.0.
I'm not using fixture, juste passing some data to the controller as the example.
I think you didn't understand what I did, in the controller i do different action in the function and I need to recover data from other models and it works. The problem is only when i call the function with testAction.